# Converting Binary to bitmap image for imagelist. Code Error

Tags: c#, bitmap, binary

I am having issues with the below code for converting the binary source to a bitmap image to insert into my imagelist. I am receiving "Parameter is not Valid".

```
// Retrieving data from Database
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vcon.Open();
        string get = "Select Path, Images FROM IMGSTR";
        OleDbCommand cmdget = new OleDbCommand(get, vcon);
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        reader = cmdget.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string path = reader["Path"].ToString();

            //here is where I am receiving an error
            this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream((byte[]) reader["Images"])));


             //creates rows in my listview to display images
            Graphics theGraphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
            int count = this.listView1.Items.Count;
            for (; count < this.imageList1.Images.Count; count++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add("", count);
            }


        }



     //Add Photos and Path to Database
    private void importImagesToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog dig = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (dig.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This May take a while. Depending on the size and amount of your photos. Click Ok to continue", "! ! !");
            foreach (String files in Directory.GetFiles(dig.SelectedPath))
            {
                if (files.EndsWith(".JPG"))
                {
                    //convert .jpg to thumbnail
                    Image image = new Bitmap(files);
                    Image pThumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new IntPtr());

                    //Insert Path and Image into database
                    string cmdstr = "INSERT into IMGSTR(Path, Images) values(path, image)";
                    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, vcon);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("path", files);

                    //Storing Image into MS database as Ole Object
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("image", pThumbnail);

                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    image.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

can anyone help me understand why i am receiving this error. I am new at computer programming and do not see why myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
//you are casting the blob from pulled from the db to a byte array
while(reader.Read())
{
    this.imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromStream(
        new MemoryStream((byte[] reader["Images"])
}
```

But in my experience, images tend to be stored on the server, and you add a path (link) to the file in the database, as adding the blob and reading it back are very heavy operations for the database.

Comment: I actually do have that code. but the window cut it off. The scroll bar will show the rest.

Comment: then i think the problem is you are not actually specifying an image, you need to loop through each image you have selected from your database.

Comment: hmm.. still not working. I'll mess with it for a couple hours and if I can't get it to work, I will try and find another solution. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: try querying ms server to see what you get, ill try to recreate your solution and get the image displaying.

Comment: @JosiahSafley the code i've posted retreives the image and adds it to the image list, can you pherhaps show me what it is you are adding to the database?

Comment: I have just added most of my code above. I have how I store the Image into the database and how I retrieve the Image.